# (Why) is $NP\subseteq coNP/poly$ same as $coNP\subseteq NP/poly$?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

If I rememeber right, I read somewhere that $NP\subseteq coNP/poly$ is the same as $coNP\subseteq NP/poly$. Is this true? If yes, is there a relatively simple proof for this?

### Definitions

**Class $NP/poly$**.
We say that a language $L$ belongs to the complexity class $NP/poly$ if there is a Turing machine $M$ and a sequence of strings $\{a_n\colon n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ called advice, such that the following hold.

- Machine $M$, when given an input $x$ of length $n$, has access to the string $a_n$ and has to decide whether $x\in L$. Machine $M$ works in nondeterministic polynomial time.
- $|a_n|\leq p(n)$ for some polynomial $p$.

$coNP/poly$ is the complement of $NP/poly$.

*Is the following definition correct?*

**Class $coNP/poly$**.
We say that a language $L$ belongs to the complexity class $coNP/poly$ if there is a Turing machine $M$ and a sequence of strings $\{a_n\colon n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ called advice, such that such that the following hold.

- Machine $M$, when given an input $x$ of length $n$, has access to the string $a_n$ and has to decide whether $x\notin L$. Machine $M$ works in nondeterministic polynomial time.
- $|a_n|\leq p(n)$ for some polynomial $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition,
$$
L \in \mathsf{coNP} \Longleftrightarrow \overline{L} \in \mathsf{NP} \\
L \in \mathsf{coNP/poly} \Longleftrightarrow \overline{L} \in \mathsf{NP/poly}
$$
From this you can easily deduce your claim.